# Reading animated PNGs in Python?

Tags: python, png, apng

[PyPNG](https://pythonhosted.org/pypng/ex.html#reading), the most widely used PNG library for Python, doesn't seem to support animated PNGs. There's a library for [writing animated PNGs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpngw), but I can't find an equivalent one for reading them. Anyone know a way of getting the frames out of this little supported image format?

Comment: Well, asking for a library that does would be off topic. However, even if there is such a library, one thing you can do yourself is look into the source code of the [`write_apng()`](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/numpngw/blob/master/numpngw.py#L969) encoder and just write your own decoder based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a library for APNGs now - https://github.com/eight04/pyAPNG

```
> pip install apng
```

Extract frames from APNG file:

```
from apng import APNG

im = APNG.open("animation.png")
i = 0
for png, control in im.frames:
    png.save("{i}.png".format(i=i))
    i += 1
```

It also supports creating APNGs.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, I found it was easiest just to invoke [APNG Disassembler](http://apngdis.sourceforge.net/) via command line, then open the disassembled frames. Hope this helps someone!